# Jquery div fixed up to other div

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

Just a newbie here.

I'm trying to trigger a div that would stay fixed and make it disappear after reach another div. My code is very basic, most of it css. My approach has been making the this div appears via scrollTop and then I have tried to make it disappear via css display:none.

I dunno if that is the correct aproach. I am just starting with JS, and I have not that much knowledge.

And btw, sorry about my english.

And this is the code:

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.iconbar').offset().top;
var end = $(".end").offset().bottom;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        $('.iconbar').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: "200",
            left: 'auto',
            right:'8px'
        });
    } else if (currentScroll >= end) {
                $(".iconbar)".css({
                    display: "none"
                }))
    } else {
        $('.iconbar').css({
        position: "static",
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 2000px;
}
.iconbar {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.iconbar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #70bcaf;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.iconbar a:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #70bcaf;
    color: white;
}

.facebook {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.twitter {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.google {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.mail {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}
.whatsapp {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}
.more {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
</div>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="iconbar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="end"></div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question clearly. Could you please make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a <div> fixed and then make it stop in the position or make it disappear once its reach another <div>. I am try to add to my webpage social icons that only stay fixed in between certain position (readable content). You can run the code snippet and scroll down to see what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I googled "Sliding header" and got this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp - is that along the lines of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you wanna '.iconbar' fixed when the user is seeing '.content' of the page? And when it is the end of '.content' or meets '.end' , '.iconbar' disappears?

Comment: which `<div>` are you talking about?

Comment: Yes @ChanjungKim, that is what I am trying to do... <div class="iconbar"> then make it stop at <div class="end">

Comment: Pretty much @theGleep, but I want to make it stop been fixed in a certain position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the top properties of '.content' and '.end'. Then you can compare with the current top position of Scrollbar.

Since all the top properties of '.content' and '.end' are different, you can implement the function you want.

Whenever it meets the top of '.content' div, it shows the menu. But If it meets the top of '.end' div, it hides the menu.

Check my sample here:

```js
//var fixmeTop = $('.iconbar').offset().top;
//var end = $(".end").offset().bottom;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.content').each(function(index){
        var contentTop = $(this).position().top;
        var isPassed = contentTop - currentScroll;

//        console.log('c: '+currentScroll + ' '+ contentTop + ' ' + isPassed);

        if(isPassed <= 30 || isPassed > -30){
//            console.log('show');
            $('.iconbar').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.iconbar a').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $('.end').each(function(index){
        var endTop = $(this).position().top;
        var isPassed = endTop - currentScroll;
//        console.log('e: '+currentScroll + ' '+ endTop + ' ' + isPassed);

        if(isPassed <= 30){
//            console.log('hide');
            $('.iconbar').css('position', 'none');
            $('.iconbar a').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
//    console.log('==============');
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 2000px;
}
.iconbar {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.iconbar a {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #70bcaf;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.iconbar a:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #70bcaf;
    color: white;
}

.facebook {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.twitter {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.google {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.mail {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}
.whatsapp {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}
.more {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:3px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;

  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
}

.end{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background:green;
}

.iconbar{
  display: none,
  position: fixed,
  top: 200px,
  left: auto,
  right:8px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="iconbar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="end"></div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: It is pretty much what I need, but I want it to trigger the function once the div ".iconbar" is reached. I am getting there! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you out. :)